# Vuex initial state lost after token answer

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuex

I try to get value of an `username` field  inside of  a `JWT` from `DRF` `response` using `VueJs`, I set my initial state inside a `vuex` module:

```
function initialState() {
  return {
    accessKey: null,
    refreshKey: null,
    username: '',
    alertMessage: null,

  }
}
export const mutations = {
  setUserKey(state, payload) {
    state.accessKey = payload.accessKey;
    state.refreshKey = payload.refreshKey;
    state.username = payload.username;
    state.expiration = Date.now() + 1
  },
};
export const actions = {
  async loginUser(context, payload) {
    try {
      const response = await DjangoAPI.login(payload);
      context.commit('setUserKey',{
        accessKey: response.data.access,
        refreshKey: response.data.refresh,
        username: response.data.username
      });
      return Promise.resolve(response);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('err in user.actions/loginUser', err)
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

when I check `vuex` initial values in `localStorage` i can see `username` field:

```
user: {accessKey: null, refreshKey: null, expiration: 0, username: ""}
accessKey: null
alertMessage: null
expiration: 0
refreshKey: null
username: ""
```

But after login, I can get other values but username field is lost:

```
user: {,…}
accessKey: "eyJ0eXAi...PmQU_I"
alertMessage: null
expiration: 1590318917105
refreshKey: "eyJ0eXA...GdCgI"
```

if I check `JWT` values, I can see `username` in my `payload`:

```
{
 "token_type": "access",
 "exp": 1590319633,
 "jti": "1556edbab9dd47349138fd98a1f8babc",
 "user_id": 1,
 "username": "ytsejam",
 "bio": "",
 "iat": 1590316033
}
```

Why does `username` field is removed after `response`?

Thanks

edit1:

console.log(response):

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "/api/obtain/token/", method: "post", data: "{"username":"ytsejam","password":"ne12veryt.."}", headers: {…}, baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/", …}
data:
access: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwMzIyMzc5LCJqdGkiOiIyNDJjNTA3YzM0MWU0N2Y3OTE0MGU0YmNjNGQ5NWQ1MSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoieXRzZWphbSIsImJpbyI6IiJ9.--7cLjVFAvYG8G0TCGh5_6J2foE2h0lEa9K8okUYN4U"
refresh: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTU5MTUzMTY3OSwianRpIjoiMjQ0Y2UxMTgzNDk5NDFiZDk4YjlmYTk1MGRkMjdkZTEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Inl0c2VqYW0iLCJiaW8iOiIifQ.b_ONU8yR4LculKQOyw_6aNZnvGdOWbruV48_OhNKYhU"
__proto__: Object
headers: {access-control-allow-credentials: "true", access-control-allow-origin: "http://localhost:8000", allow: "POST, OPTIONS", content-language: "tr", content-length: "518", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

`DRF` view using `SimpleJWT` package:

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super(MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, cls).get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['bio'] = user.bio
        return token

class ObtainTokenPairWithColorView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Comment: in the JWT payload there is username field indeed, but there are no 'refresh' and 'access' fields. Where are these fields come from?

Comment: In the loginUser function, I set them committing setUserKey, I have a problem with username field, I know there is mistake to set it, but still i dont understand why vuex completely removes the field instead of a wrong answer.

Comment: why there is localStorage here? do you use any `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` in your code when writing and loading vuex state with storage

Comment: @ytsejam It does that only when the value is undefined, so the only explanation is that the payload does not contain the 'username' field. I think that the payload you posted is not the one that the loginUser function receives, since there are no 'refresh' and 'access' fields in it.

Comment: according to your comment @IgorMoraru , I have console.logged the payload answer and I have only access and refresh in my response data.  username is inside access but i dont know how to filter that payload from it. I think I am gonna create a custom view to get user information. that is better approach I think, am I right?

Comment: @JakeLam I took localStorage values from application tab inside chrome developer tools.

Comment: could you add to your question the console.logged response and the DRF view?

Comment: @IgorMoraru I have added answer and view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach to add custom fields to JWT response is to rewrite the validate() method instead of get_token():

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        # Add custom claims
        data['username'] = self.user.username
        data['bio'] = self.user.bio
        return data
```

Then you will have 'username' and 'bio' fields in response.data, along with 'access' and 'refresh'.